# can you spot the mistake?

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, adminlte

[this is the ui when running on my localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuwOy.png)

[this is the ui when running on cpanel hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEM5v.png)

my question is, what is wrong with the ui? everytime i run my application on server, the sidebar always gone wrong

for little information, i use Laravel 5.6 and AdminLTE3 template.

the top navbar and the sidebar is at different .blade.php file. i combine them in master template that contains them (using @include) and the content of page (using @yield).

[my master.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZKH9.png)

is there anything's wrong with my code, or, this is the bugs from adminLTE 3?

thanks for your help.

Comment: i think this is like css error and javascript, just open view page source and try to check if javascript external file and css is pointing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was seen your web & I tried to understand your problem. I found 3 errors in console related to your css files. I think that problem happens because that css file errors. but i can't understand why it shown that errors in console. I attached snapshot of that error, see this below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysgzy.png)

Comment: thank you for helping me. just known to check the console. i delete the overlayscrollable.min.js from the site. so its running like a charm. thanks again and again.